# How can I change this product cart to a right-bottom using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the link to the source code  - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nnlmytU3I1Zg7_kXabdQmcCeCe26uOvB?usp=sharing

This is what I want - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nv0qr9JraD1tQX1cj2kzLSHD8X7IuAu-/view?usp=sharing

I want to move the add-cart to the bottom right corner using CSS. I used this. But I couldn't do that.

```
.add-cart {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #382a30;
  color: #00f919;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Please check the src file to view the HTML file.

Comment: Please add your code as a StackOverflow code snippet.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `position: relative` to the `.product-box`:

```
.product-box {
  position: relative;
}
```

[image]

Comment: But it is not going to work for me.I do not know why? I did like that